# queuable mails not working

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I have a problem.
It has something to do with laravel queuable emails.
Basically when I join tables and try to dispatch mails i always get 404 not found error,
but if i var dump the users object i get email and everything I've wanted to. What could cause this ?

Sending mail:

```
    if ($request->get("group") == 11) {
        $users = Paper::AcceptedPhase(2)->get(["email"]);

        foreach($users as $user) {
            SendMessageEmail::dispatch($user, $message);
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Scope:

```
public function scopeAcceptedPhase($query, $id) {
      return $query->join('authors', 'authors.paper_id', '=', 'papers.id')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'authors.user_id')
                 ->where("papers.status",$id)->distinct();
}
```

Mail:

class SendMessageEmail implements ShouldQueue {

```
use Dispatchable,
    InteractsWithQueue,
    Queueable,
    SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $user;
public $message;

public function __construct($user, $message) {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle() 
{
    Mail::to($this->user->email)->send(new MessageMail($this->user, $this->message));
}
```

}

I'm basically getting 404 page, what could be causing this?

Comment: Is there anything written to the error log?

Comment: No, it only throws 404 not found :S